# Wrong time in time counter in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, counter, barcode

I am organizing a race, and I need a system to scan the bibs of the runners at their arrival.
My barcode scanner behave similarly to a keyboard: when I scan something I have a string, in my case name, surname and bib number.
So I need a counter that starts when the race starts and I need recording the time of each runner.
I tried to use datetime.datetime and time.perf_counter, but the values I get are wrong
(I put both and ntp for comparison, I need just one)

```
import time
from time import ctime
import datetime
import ntplib

#getting time just for comparison purposes
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('pool.ntp.org')
print(ctime(response.tx_time))


start_time_perf = time.perf_counter()
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
 

 now_time_perf = time.perf_counter()
 now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
 elapsed_perf = (now_time_perf - start_time_perf)
 elapsed = (now_time - start_time)
 barcode = input() # I scan here
 
 now_ntp = c.request('pool.ntp.org')
 print(ctime(now_ntp.tx_time))
 #print(elapsed_perf)
 elapsed_formatted=(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_perf)))
 print(barcode, elapsed, elapsed_formatted)
```

I have outputs like this one:

```
Sun Apr 25 16:12:57 2021
Lucy P 13
Sun Apr 25 16:13:02 2021
Lucy P  0:00:00.000010 00:00:00
Jen P 18
Sun Apr 25 16:13:04 2021
Jen P 18 0:00:04.124914 00:00:04
Tiziana D 19
Sun Apr 25 16:13:06 2021
Tiziana D 19 0:00:06.577438 00:00:06
Reka H 17
Sun Apr 25 16:13:07 2021
Reka H 17 0:00:08.096890 00:00:08
Myriam F 20
Sun Apr 25 16:13:12 2021
Myriam F 20 0:00:09.585379 00:00:09
Caroline W 14
Sun Apr 25 16:13:13 2021
Caroline W 14 0:00:15.000074 00:00:15
```

As you can see the time interval is wrong...
Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain which time interval is wrong?

Comment: well as you can see, timer started at 16:12:57. When I scanned Lucy at 16:13:02 five seconds passed but counter display 00:00:00. When I scan Jen at 16:13:04 , seven seconds passed, but counter shows 00:00:04 seconds of difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating elapsed time right after the user input will fix your issue.

```
barcode = input() # scan here
elapsed = (now_time - start_time)
```

Otherwise the amount of time user spending on input will not be added to the difference.

Comment: Sorry you are right! There is still a small difference but it is ok! thanks